# RSS feed box next to a Facebook box

Tags: html, facebook

Sorry, but I am giving up... On my page I have both a "Find us on Facebook" box and a RSS news feed box. I cant get them to align next to each other no matter what I do. Ok, I am not a great programmer, but this must be able to work? Please do help if you can. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://output53.rssinclude.com/output?type=js&amp;id=821171&amp;hash=ca29499e740c15811af82b85d2ad3eed"></script>


<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/kyrkplatsen" data-width="300" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Put them in a table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><FB div></td>
        <td><RSS div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Option 2: Use unordered list with `display:inline`.

Hope this works.